# Bound on number of mutually orthonormal eigenfunctions

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, eigenfunctions

Let $E$ be the vector space of real valued continuous functions on an interval $[a,b]$.  Let $K = K(x,y)$ be a continuous function of two variables, defined on the square $a \leq x \leq b$ and $a \leq y \leq b$.  An element $f$ of $E$ is said to be an eigenfunction for $K$, with respect to a real number $r$, if
$$f(y) = r\int_{a}^{b} K(x,y)f(x)\,dx.$$
We take $E$ with the $L^{2}$-norm of the hermitian product given by
$$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{a}^{b} fg.$$
Prove that if $f_{1}, \dotsc, f_{n}$ are in $E$, mutually orthogonal, and of $L^{2}$-nrom equal to 1, and if they are eigenfunctions with respect to the same number $r$, then $n$ is bounded by a number depending only on $K$ and $r$. [Hint: Aply Bessel's inequality.]

I assume that I am supposed to cleverly choose an element of $E$ and then use Bessel's inequality, but I have not found the proper element.  I tried setting $g=\sum f_{i}$ and showing that $g$ is also an eigenfunction for $(K,r)$.  But I wasn't able to get much further.  Using the orthogonality of the $f_{i}$, I did show that $\lvert g\rvert^{2} = n$, but this follows from the Pythagoras Theorem.

Comment: What is $K(x,y)$? What is $C(K,r)$?

Comment: Sorry, both sources I looked at used $K$, so I thought it was universal.

Comment: What is the relation of $n$ to everything else? And please write down the operator for which the $f_i$ are eigenfunctions.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it and put up the exact problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you  mean the eigenfunctions of an integral operator $K$ with kernel $K(x,y)$ and if $K(x,y)$ is assumed, say, to be continuous in $(x,y)$, then the operator $K$ is compact and hence any eigenvalue $\lambda$ has finite multiplicity (because $K\lambda$ is compact and at the same time is the identity operator on the eigenspace).

Comment: So the statement is wrong unless one assumes additionally $r \ne 0$.

Comment: Exactly. For example, if $K(x,y)=0$ for $x$ or $y$ in some interval of length>0, then you have infinitely many eigenfunctions with zero eigenvalue.

Comment: according to the edit by the OP, $r^{-1}$ is the eigenvalue, not $r$.

Comment: @HansEngler you are right. I have edited my post.

Comment: @Vladimir I apologize for the confusion in the problem statement, I tried to be too colloquial. This exercise was from a first section on Hilbert spaces. I'm unsure what a compact operator is. Would you be able to provide a more elementary answer?